# Cloudflare SSL или letsencrypt

Tags: node.js, ssl, https, letsencrypt, cloudflare

Всем привет! Есть сайт на амазоне с `NodeJS`. Через `Cloudflare` к нему привязан домен. Решил узнать как лучше прикрутить `https` к сайту.

Варианта есть два:

1. Использовать `ssl` от `cloudflare`.
2. Использовать `ssl` от `letsencrypt`.

Собственно какой сертификат в каких случаях лучше использовать? Какие есть нюансы?

Comment: И у тех, и у других должны быть описания на официальных сайтах со всеми нюансами, не?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Let's Encrypt

**Плюсы**

- Работает на любых доменах
- Можно поставить обновление срока действия по cron

**Минусы**

- Срок действия - три месяца
- Требует добавления промежуточного сертификата

### Cloudflare

**Плюсы**

- Срок действия - 15 лет сразу

**Минусы**

- Работает только на доменах, чьи NS размещены на Cloudflare
- Работает только при включенном кешировании домена (оранжевое облако в DNS CloudFlare). Не очень удобно при разработке сайта, приходится ставить режим Development Mode в разделе Cache
- Требует включения режима SLL "Full (Strict)" в разделе Crypto
- Требует добавления промежуточного сертификата CloudFlare в сгенерированный сертификат сайта. Подробнее [здесь](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/218689638-What-are-the-root-certificate-authorities-CAs-used-with-Cloudflare-Origin-CA-)

Вместе с тем, по личному опыту, если домен размещен на CloudFlare, использую сертификат CloudFlare. К минусам привык, а отсутствие головной боли с обновлением сертификата перевешивает эти минусы, на мой взгляд.

Comment: «Срок действия - полгода» — нет, три месяца. Причём подумывают уменьшать до одного месяца. И это не минус, а плюс :)

Comment: «Требует добавления промежуточного сертификата CloudFlare» — Let's Encrypt тоже требует, кстати

Comment: @andreymal да, точно, три месяца. Не знаю даже, откуда полгода вылезло ).

Comment: @andreymal возможно. У меня Let's Encrypt вставал автоматом с помощью их бота, я ничего руками не добавлял

Comment: `certbot` создаёт четыре файлика: `cert`, `chain`, `fullchain` и `privkey`. `cert` — это созданный сам сертификат, `chain` — тот самый промежуточный. `fullchain` — объединение первых двух аналогично как у CloudFlare. В принципе современные браузеры хавают LE и без промежуточного, однако без него случаются проблемы на, например, некоторых старых андроидах, поэтому лучше считать, что LE требует промежуточный сертификат (по крайней мере в ближайшие несколько лет)

Comment: @andreymal возможно, я просто не сталкивался с этим, повезло. Добавлю в ответ